# Grunt.js task for joining .html files (surrounding content with a string) and injecting the result into an single file?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I have many `.html` files (AngularJS templates) and I want to join them in a single file, reading all their content and surrounding the content with a `<script>` tag.

Example:

- `/path/to/a.html`
- `/path/to/b.html`

Contents:

```
<!-- a.html -->
<h1>I'm A</h1>

<!-- b.html -->
<h1>I'm B</h1>
```

Wanted task result (`output.html`):

```
    <!-- html, body, etc -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/path/to/a.html">
        <h1>i'm A</h1>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/path/to/b.html">
        <h1>i'm B</h1>
    </script>
</body>
```

Eventually, I would like to customize the `id` of template (full path to `.html` template), shortening the path if needed.

**EDIT**: thanks to the comments I was able to do something like:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
        options: {
          process: function (src, filepath) {
            return '<script type="text/ng-template" id="'+filepath+'">\r\n'+src+'</script>\r\n';
          }
        },
        dist: {
            src: ['partials/**/*.html'],
            dest: 'dist/out.html',
        },
    }
});
```

But how to define `dist/out.html` as a template itself (inserting the output into a placeholder)?

Comment: You might be looking for this: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat

Comment: @Tony good catch, i was able to process contents, how do i place the content in my final output file (without overriding it every time)?

Comment: Hi, I was trying the same and as mentioned by @Tony, grunt-contrib-concat has event callback called process: `function(src, filepath)`. You can process the file surrounding it with the script tag and return it afterwards.

Comment: @HimmetAvsar it works, but now I can't place the output in a given html file... see my edits, thanks.

Comment: First, glad you got some stuff working. Sounds like what you want to do is concat your files and then insert them into a certain spot in `dist/out.html`? Try this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-insert

Comment: @Tony found grunt-html-build it seems exactly what i need! You should group your comments to make an answer I can accept.

Comment: Wonderful! And done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

You should be able to group all your angular templates together using [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat).

The concatted file can be inserted into a designed file using something like [grunt-insert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-insert) or, as your found, `grunt-html-build`.